# Speed Limit differences between Rest API and Map Creator

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest, heremaps, heremap-navigation

We've been looking into a few scenario's whereby the Rest API returns a different speed limit result to that of Map Creator for a given long / lat and bearing.

My best guess would be that due to Map Creator allowing editing of speed limits, you don't immediately push those changes to your core database for use by other API's.

Would you be able to shed some light on the following:

1. Is there's a verification process performed by your staff to confirm any speed limit changes made in Map Creator?
2. What is the turnaround time for this step?
3. How soon after a change is verified, does it become available to the Rest API?
4. Is there a notification process we can hook into to be notified of speed limit changes for the Rest API?

**An example would be:**

*Latitude,Longitude,Heading
-34.7873726,138.5807025,199*

**Rest API gives me a 90km/hr speed limit**

- URL : https://rme.cit.api.here.com/2/matchroute.json?file=bGF0aXR1ZGUsbG9uZ2l0dWRlLGhlYWRpbmcKLTM0Ljc4NzM3MjYsMTM4LjU4MDcwMjUsMTk5&routemode=car&attributes=SPEED_LIMITS_FCn(FROM_REF_SPEED_LIMIT,TO_REF_SPEED_LIMIT)&app_id={{app_id}}&app_code={{app_code}}
- `{
  "RouteLinks": [
      {
          "functionalClass": 1,
          "confidence": 1.0,
          "linkId": -1211546049,
          "attributes": {
              "SPEED_LIMITS_FCN": [
                  {
                      "FROM_REF_SPEED_LIMIT": "0",
                      "TO_REF_SPEED_LIMIT": "90"
                  }
              ]
          },
          "mSecToReachLinkFromStart": 40,
          "linkLength": 0.0,
          "shape": "-34.78737 138.5807 -34.78737 138.5807"
      }
  ],
  "TracePoints": [
      {
          "confidenceValue": 1.0,
          "elevation": 0.0,
          "headingDegreeNorthClockwise": 199.0,
          "headingMatched": -163.0,
          "lat": -34.7873726,
          "latMatched": -34.78737,
          "linkIdMatched": -1211546049,
          "lon": 138.5807025,
          "lonMatched": 138.5807,
          "matchDistance": 0.86,
          "matchOffsetOnLink": 0.43468916306434047,
          "minError": 1.0,
          "routeLinkSeqNrMatched": 0,
          "speedMps": 0.0,
          "timestamp": 0
      }
  ],
  "Warnings": [],
  "MapVersion": "LATEST"
  }`

**Map Creator shows 110km/hr**

https://mapcreator.here.com/navlink:1211546049/?l=-34.7874,138.5807,18,normal

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, there is process defined for edits and modifications that involves like collection, verification, integration and delivery. The edits are prioritised based many factors.
2. Turn around time is not specific, but integrations happened daily. Prioritised edits work around time is less than 14 days, Trusted user program etc.
3. Once the changes are reviewed by experts and deployed on service, REST API shows the immediate results.
4. You can create watchlist for keeping track of your edits and feedbacks.

[image]